# Prove the solution of first order ODE is sum of homogeneous and particular solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $I \subseteq R$ be an interval and $f,g:I \to \mathbb R$ two functions. If there exists a solution $y_\text{part}:I \to \mathbb R$ of the ODE $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$, then the general solution is of the form $y = y_\text{part} + y_\text{hom}$, where $y_\text{hom}$ is the general solution to the homogeneous ODE $y' + f(x)y = 0$.

I know that I need to show that $y = y_\text{part} + y_\text{hom}$ is a solution and then that it is the only solution. However I'm struggling to prove this general theorem, because unlike in excercises I have no concrete formula for $y_\text{part}$, so I can't compute the derivative of $y$ and plug it in the equality to see that it is a solution. I know only that $y_\text{hom}$ is of the form $y_\text{hom} = Ae^{-F(x)}$ where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Can I prove this without specifying the formula for $y_\text{part}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the general solution of the homogeneous  ODE has the form
$$y_\text{hom}(x)=Ay_h(x)=Ae^{-F(x)},\quad A\in\mathbb R.$$
Let $y =Ay_h+y_\text{part}$, then
$$
y'+f(x)y= Ay'_h+y'_\text{part}+f(x)\left( Ay_h+y_\text{part} \right)
$$
$$
=A\left( y'_h+f(x)y_h \right)+ \left( y'_\text{part}+f(x)y_\text{part} \right)
=A\cdot 0+g(x)=g(x),
$$
thus, any function of the form $Ay_h+y_\text{part}$ is a solution of the original ODE.

Consider the initial value problem 
$$
y'(x)+f(x)y=g(x),\quad y(x_0)=y_0.
$$
Substituting the initial condition into the solution, one obtains
$$
y(x_0)=Ae^{-F(x_0)}+y_\text{part}(x_0)=y_0
$$
and
$$\tag{1}
A=e^{F(x_0)}\left( y_0-y_\text{part}(x_0)\right).
$$
Hence, any solution of the original ODE can be writen in the form
$$
y=Ae^{-F(x)}+y_\text{part}(x),
$$
where $A$ can be determined from (1).

Comment: Thanks! For the second part regarding the uniqueness of the solution: I initially thought about assuming there are two partial solutions $y_{p,1},y_{p,2}$ and then showing that those differ only by a homogenous solution. But *why* does that tell me that with $y = y_{p,1} + y_h$ alone I have found the general solution?

Comment: @philmcole It doesn't. This is why we need the second part. The second part refers to the existence, not to the uniqueness. We have proved that for any initial values $x_0$, $y_0$ the solution of the form $y_\text{hom}+y_\text{part}$ exists.

Comment: @philmcole The uniqueness is given by the Picard–Lindelöf theorem